# Impresion de datos usando procemidmientos

Tags: c#

Buen dia, soy nuevo en C# y estoy atascado en un ejercicio que me piden de la uni, el programa funciona pero me piden que hagan uso de un procedimiento para mostrarlo en pantalla y de la formas como lo he hecho funcionan. Gracias de antemano.

```
namespace vehiculos_procedimiento
{
   struct Vehiculos
   { 
      public int placa;
      public string color;
      public int año;
      public string marca;
      public string modelo;
      public string propietario;

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Vehiculos Var = new Vehiculos();
         int max;
         Console.WriteLine("ingrese la cantidad de vehiculos");
         max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         Vehiculos[] carros = new Vehiculos[max];
         Console.WriteLine("\n");

         for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese la marca del vehiculo");
            carros[i].marca = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese modelo del vehiculo");
            carros[i].modelo = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el color del vehiculo");
            carros[i].color = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el año del vehiculo");
            carros[i].año = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese la placa del vehiculo");
            carros[i].placa = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese nombre del propietario");
            carros[i].propietario = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("la informacion de  sus vehiculos es");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Vehiculo n°:[" + (i + 1) + "]");
            Console.WriteLine("marca: " + carros[i].marca);
            Console.WriteLine("modelo: " + carros[i].modelo);
            Console.WriteLine("color: " + carros[i].color);
            Console.WriteLine("año: " + carros[i].año);
            Console.WriteLine("placa: " + carros[i].placa);
            Console.WriteLine("propietario: " + carros[i].propietario);
            Console.ReadKey();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Debes crear un procedimiento en tu motor de BD, y llamar a dicho procedimiento desde C#. Supongo que es eso

Comment: Buen día Eduardo, por lo que entiendo debes obtener los datos mediante un procedimiento.Dentro de tu main, antes del for, podrias llamar al procedimiento CaracteristicasCarro(carros); de esta manera haces llamar a dicho procedimiento, qué será tu ciclo for.

Answer (score -1):

Anexo ejemplos de un código que estoy desarrollando, para que entiendas como llamar al procedimiento dentro de tu main, y que compone dicho procedimiento dentro de la clase del programa.

Llamada al procedimiento:
[image: Llamada al procedimiento]

instrucciones del procedimiento/método

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo la respuesta y no entiendo como llamas al procedimiento almacenado, parece que te equivocaste de pregunta, porque estas trabajando con un zip segun lo que veo.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude hacer

Comment: este es un codigo de ejemplo, no me puse a desarrollar el problema particular que tenia Eduardo, solo le comparti partes de mi programa para esta parte de procedimientos y como funcionan @RamiroBarone